# What is an alternative way to sum a column without aggregate function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I using a software where is partly SQL server based. The software is made by another company so I do not have full access to the sql editing part. In simple terms, I have a datebase and it is stored using sql formats. I can fiddle with some areas but there are limitation to how much I can customize and the type of syntax that can be used.

Aggregate function such as SUM() cannot be used and I am trying to find an alternative method to reach a similar/same result. I know that the normal way to sum is as below but SUM() and GROUP BY cannot be used.
I am still inexperienced in sql, I kindly ask for your advices.
Thank you very much in advance.

DBMS: Microsoft SQL server

```
SELECT *,SUM(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY ID1
```

Note:
ID1 continues to expand
ID2 consist a fix set of value (AA, BB, CC, DD, EE) ONLY

I don't need to group it but I don't know how to do it without grouping at the moment

TABLE

| ID1 | ID2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | AA | 10 |
| 001 | BB | 21 |
| 001 | CC | 2 |
| 001 | DD | 16 |
| 002 | AA | 7 |
| 002 | CC | 8 |
| 003 | AA | 10 |
| 003 | BB | 9 |
| 003 | AA | 11 |

RESULT

| ID1 | ID2 | Value | SUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | AA | 10 | 49 |
| 001 | BB | 21 | 49 |
| 001 | CC | 2 | 49 |
| 001 | DD | 16 | 49 |
| 002 | AA | 7 | 15 |
| 002 | CC | 8 | 15 |
| 003 | AA | 10 | 30 |
| 003 | BB | 9 | 30 |
| 003 | AA | 11 | 30 |

Comment: Your SQL query causes a syntax error, and it's not clear why you can/will not use SUM() function, and what kind of DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sql syntax varies by vendor and version, so always include that information in any sql questions. You can [Edit] the question to include your DBMS in the question tags.

Comment: BTW: In your query is a column 'X', which is not in your example data......   Are you NEW to SO ?  Please [edit] and make it a [mre]

Comment: @Luuk, thank you very much for the comments. I have edit the question in attempt to provide a better understanding of the situation. I have also edit the syntax to refer back to the example.

Comment: You did forget to add the type of DBMS, but this question sound like you should find the DBA, an ask him to give you more access.

Comment: You could fetch all the rows and sum them yourself, but that is inefficient. Since this is custom software providing some limited subset of SQL you'll have to ask the people who made it how you're supposed to do aggregates without `group by` or ask your DBA for more access. Or perhaps they can make you a [`view`](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_view.asp) which does what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind advice, Luuk and @Schwern. I have talked to the DBA I will try to ask again. I will research about VIEW too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using the window function `sum() over()`.  Notice there is no need for a GROUP BY or subquery.

The window functions are invaluable and well worth your time getting comfortable with them.

**Example**

```
Select * 
      ,Sum = sum(Value) over (partition by ID1)
 From  YourTable
```

Results

```
ID1     ID2     Value   Sum
001     AA      10      49
001     BB      21      49
001     CC      2       49
001     DD      16      49
002     AA      7       15
002     CC      8       15
003     AA      10      30
003     BB      9       30
003     AA      11      30
```